# Normalizing MySQL table with records of another table

Tags: mysql, normalization

i have 2 tables. The city tables is not normalized because the country information is in plain text. I have added the id_country to the 'city' table (that column is empty).

I need to check for matches between **city>country** and **country>country** and then update the city records that matched with the id_country from the country table. At the end i will be able to delete the 'country' column from the city table.

**City table**

- id_city (1, 2,  3...)
- city (Washington, Guayaquil, Bonn...)
- country (Germany, Ecuador, USA...)
- id_country (currently empty)

**Country table**

- id_country (1, 2, 3...)
- code (GE, EC, US...)
- country (Germany, Ecuador, USA...)

I have no idea on where to start and if it can be done with a SQL query. My original idea was to search for matches in a php loop but that seems to be a really harder implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a JOIN on an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE city c1 INNER JOIN country c2 ON c1.country=c2.country
SET c1.id_country=c2.id_country;
```

Using an `INNER JOIN` will make sure that updates only occur for cities that have a matching country value.

Once you've run it, you'll be able to select all those cities that still have a null id_country just in case some of them didn't match.  Conversely, once you've determined that all your cities have an id_country, you can delete that column from the city table.

Comment: Done! 3500 records, 81 where without country. You saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> The city tables is not normalized because the country information is
>   in plain text.

Nonsense. Normalization doesn't mean "replace plain text with id numbers". Find whoever taught you that and poke him in the eye with a sharp stick.

Your *real* problem is that "city" plus "country" isn't sufficient to identify cities, at least in the USA. I think there are at least a dozen different cities named "Washington" in the USA.

Instead of replacing the country name with an id number, you'd be far better off replacing it with the two-letter country code. The codes are human-readable; the id numbers will require an additional JOIN in every query that uses your table of cities.

Comment: not quite. it is not a "city" table per se, i changed the name of the table to avoid confusions. it is an airports table, where each airport is on a specific city. the id_country is for placing the country flag only.

Comment: "i changed the name of the table to avoid confusions." Ah. If only that had worked. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE city set id_country = (SELECT country.id_country from country WHERE country.country = city.country)
```